# Form on entity linked to a relation

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms

I have these entities :

[image]

Now, I need to create form to store data.

My problem is, I don't know how to figure out to create those forms.
What I want is a form where I can create a User, and here, I can select a Pack.

When I selected it, a list of Services of the selected pack appears, which I can checked if it is consumed by the User.

More complicated, I need to allow User to have several pack, and same pack is allowed.

It's look like a collection of User_Pack_Service form, but how to keep the Pack of each collection?

Other questions, since Pack_Service is a relation table of ManyToMany relation ship, it complicated the way of add Services in Pack. Is there a way to avoid is creation as entity? (I know I need it to link Pack and Service to User but that result in to many entities for nothing...)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: looking to your schema i would say that you can drop one table. Lets say that you drop pack_service and give user_pack_service this fields: user_id, pack_id, service_id and consumed. For the rest you need to create entities for each table and you need to use OneToMany relations for each connection . Check the doctrine association mapping page: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional

Comment: I can't remove PAck_Service. This is my reference table use to create packs and associated services.

Comment: than your user_pack_service will be your reference table. (You could change the name to pack_service also). Join tables that joins other jointables does not make sence

Comment: It can't, when I will create a Pack and Services, I will have a user_Id = null. Then I will attache a pack to user_id = 1. Now how I can attach the same pack to another user?